# InvalidOperationException: type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I upgraded to Core 1.1 and Visual Studio 2017.  I am running a simple existing line of code to search a column for a user inputted string but get the error...

> InvalidOperationException: variable '__searchTerm_1' of type
>   'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

In short my Code is:

```
public IQueryable<SearchViewModel> ActivitySearch(string searchTerm)
{
    var qry = (from act in context.Acts
                  .Include(x => x.ActivityExt)
               select new SearchViewModel()
               {
                   AMCNnumber = act.AMCNnumber
                   ActivityId = act.ActivityID,
                   ImplementingPartner = act.ActivityExt.imp,
                   ProjectTitle = act.Name,
                   Description = act.Description,
                   StartDate = act.StartDate,
                   EndDate = act.EndDate
               });

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
     {
         qry = qry.Where(x => x.AMCNnumber.Contains(searchTerm);
     } 

     return qry.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Added in more code. This search has been working for a while now but it seems like something changed with going to Core 1.1 with .Contains.

Comment: I stand corrected, projecting into non-anonymous, non-entity types appears to be supported with EF Core.

Comment: What is type for AMCNnumber property ?

Comment: Looks like a bug but do you have a workaround if you move `searchTerm` into a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a sub query which I had was causing the error.  I had to create separate variable to get an ID.